# Change navigation bar color, IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I use this code for changing the color of all nav.bar items through my viewControllers:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
```

But i can't change the color of one of my vc-s, which i use for scanning
 QR codes. If i paste this, all of my buttons and labels which is in front of camera screen hides (but back color of nav.bar become white, as i want).

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

But if i delete this line, color of nav.bar on vc with camera capturing doesn't changes. 
So my question is: is it possible to change back color of nav.bar to white while buttons and label are visible and in front of camera view?

P.S. I've used this code to make button and label in front of camera view:

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: infoLabel1)
view.bringSubview(toFront: buttonGot)
```

**EDIT**
I have fixed it, guys. Who has the same problem:
in ***AppDelegate.swift***:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue

    return true
}
```

in **viewDidLoad()**:

```
navItemTop.titleView = UIImageView(image: ViewController4.barImg)
```

And it works correctly =)

Comment: you can change the navigation bar color from the storyboard, if your  view controllers are embedded inside navigation controller

Comment: @Fahad Jamal ye, i know about it, but it doesn't solve my problem, color is still not white

Comment: can u share the screenshot of that view

Comment: http://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/2/19/7d8a415e70d340da3aedc2abe5726ef3-full.jpg

Comment: http://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/2/19/0dfe65f26ea3d1fd9e4671eed64a4699-full.jpg

Comment: is your infoLabel1 and buttonGot behind navigation bar?

Comment: Frankly speaking, i didn't think about it. How can i check it?